# How to prevent my server web socket flooding my browser clients

Tags: javascript, websocket

This is quite new to me so forgive me if this is a stupid/obvious question.

I have a web socket on my server.
I am sending around 40 jpegs as byte arrays (of approx. 12kb size each) every second.

On the client I display the image on a canvas control.

Each JPEG has a timestamp water-marked on it.

Every now and then, the time-stamp starts to lag from what is the current system time.

Sometimes several minutes old.

I would prefer to determine on the client when such a lag is abound and then somehow flush the web socket.

Is this possible?

Thanks

**ADDITIONAL**

It has been pointed out to me that just disconnecting and reconnecting should clear the socket of phantom messages.

Following is code that shows how my client reconnects if it loses connection. I had to put this in in case I did not receive a disconnect from my server:

```
function Reconnect() {
    try {
        ws = new WebSocket(url);
        ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
        ws.onerror = function (e) {
            try {
                console.log('onerror');
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        };
        ws.onclose = function () {
            try {
                Reconnect();
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        };
        ws.onopen = function () {
            try {
                StartPing();
                console.log('onopen');
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        };
        ws.onmessage = function (e) {
                try{
                  ''display image on canvas
                }
                catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            }
        };
    }
    catch (err) {
        Reconnect();
    }
}

function StartPing() {
    try{
        window.clearInterval(window.timerID);
        if (!window.timerID) { /* avoid firing a new setInterval, after one has been done */
            window.timerID = setInterval(Ping, 20000);
        }
    }
    catch (err)
    {
        console.log(err + ' Reconnect');
    }
}

function Ping() {
try {

    var now = new Date();
    var d = now.format("yyyymmddhhMMss");
    var currentTimeStamp = d + '000';
    if (parseInt(currentTimeStamp) - parseInt(lastUpdated) < 60) {
        console.log('Reconnect');
        Reconnect();
    }
    else {
        StartPing();
    }
}
catch (err) {
    console.log(err + ' Ping');
}
```

Comment: Add a timestamp to the message body.

Comment: @Amit Hi.  In my jpeg byte array I put in the header the time-stamp already. This does not stop my client being flooded though?

Comment: I would still receive the byte array...

Comment: But the client can parse that and decide to disconnect / reconnect when the lag becomes to large

Comment: HI, it was one of the things I was going to try BUT, when I just refresh my browser the disconnect/connect should happen anyway?  The jpegs are still bunched up when I do this.  So, is it perhaps that the socket has been pooled and reused do you think?

Comment: So you're getting phantom messages after refresh? doesn't sound right. I'd advise you to make sure you're not confusing something here

Comment: Hi, I am sure I am not. I will edit my question now to show you the Javascript code for my connection...

Comment: actually, I may lol.  I have set uo a PING just in case I do not receive any messages after 20 seconds. I shall add that to my question now

Comment: @Amit updated question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure you close your older WebSocket before connecting a new one, otherwise you get multiple simultaneous open connections which is not what you want (and will throw you off when trying to understand what's happening).

In your Reconnect function, do:

```
function Reconnect() {
    try {
        // ws is probably some global variable, so:
        if(ws instanceof WebSocket)
          ws.close();
        ws = new WebSocket(url);
        ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
        // Rest of code...
```

Comment: I believe that is exactly what has happened.  Thanks for pointing out what I should have realised myself. On holiday in a weeks time for much needed break.  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: BTW thank you so much. Such a silly mistake I made and it has caused so many problems all week.